# Is there a better way to commit to a Git parent branch and merge into current?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I use Sourcetree, but am happy to solve this with the command line if I need to. I have a Git repository like so:

```
- develop
    - develop-not-bc
- prod
```

`not-bc` has an SDK update in it that cannot be ported back to `develop`, and I currently require working with that SDK update. However a lot of the work I'm doing needs to be applied to `develop` as well.

Right now I'm "solving" this by:

1. Having `develop` checked out separately.
2. Copy completed changes from `not-bc` into `develop` and commit/push.
3. Merge `develop` into `not-bc` to receive the changes.

It does work, but it's also annoying, mildly time consuming and is flooding my repo history with

> Merge branch 'develop' into develop-not-bc

I'm wondering if there's a better way to manage this? Basically I want to reflect a lot (not all) of the work I'm doing in `develop`, so it is available later. I can't merge back from `not-bc` later because it will include the updated SDK and a lot of changes from it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In these cases I keep advancing the “dependency work that can’t be pulled in” *to the head* of the WIP branch using rebase. The the commits south (ancestors of) are shared and can be merged or rebased in. Using a trailing WIP branch/tag to keep track of the sync-points may also be useful.

Comment: In any case, *there is no need to copy*: a cherry-pick should suffice. Git also now allows setting up a “shared repo” (what is this called?) so at the same repo can worked on different branches in different WCs. This avoids having to context switch a WC to prepare and push changes.

Comment: Advancing the code with the dependency to the head is useful for cases when it is heavily intertwined with and/or dependent on other changes - don’t want to introduce changes requiring the dependency too early. It can however become complex when unable to synchronize at suitable times - in these cases breaking up the problem might be helpful.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for this! So I'm not sure I've done exactly what you suggested, but I believe it's in the same area: I looked into rebasing and it cleans up all of the "Merge branch" commits nicely. Whenever I do something new on `develop`, I rebase `not-bc` to that commit and receive all of the changes. Though I'm yet to solve the annoyance of wanting to commit to `develop` while working in `not-bc` easily (without changing branches). Do you know what I could look into for this?

Comment: Ah, that’s what it’s called: “worktree” - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: Thanks! However does this have any relevant benefits compared to my having cloned the repository again in another directory on the `develop` branch? It seems I still need to copy the files between an additional directory, right?

Comment: I just did some reading into it and found that it uses all the same files, so they stay up to date automatically. I like that, so I've switched it out! Unfortunately I still need to copy files between the two directories.

Comment: Actually, I could use stashes now, which would save a bit of time/manual copying!

Comment: Don’t copy files! Use rebase (-i), cherry-pick, and checkout — (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do in this scenario is to develop a feature branch from `develop-not-bc`... when I like what I see, I then move (*backport*, actually) the feature branch onto develop:

```
git rebase --onto develop develop-not-bc my-branch
```

When I make sure it works fine on `develop`, I can then merge into both `develop`  and `develop-not-bc`or wait for that branch to get the changes from `develop` itself, depending on workflow.

Comment: Thanks for this: to clarify, you branch from `not-bc`, commit to this branch, and then cherry-pick any of those commits from `develop`? If I'm understanding correctly, unfortunately this still involves having to change branches fairly often. 

I have since learned how to rebase, which solves the "Merge branch" commits flooding the history. However I'm still hopefuly there's an easier way to basically commit changes to `develop` instead of my current branch (`not-bc`).

Comment: But this is according to your specific requirement: `...and I currently require working with that SDK update` hence the idea to work on top of `non-bc`... from the point of view of git, there's no requirement at all for that and that's why the recipe is set that way instead of asking to start on top of `develop`

Comment: About your question: Not exactly, by using a separate branch (`featurex` or `fun-branch`, or `foo-bar`), you are able to skip running cherry-pick and let rebase handle those calculations for you.